# How to restructure an array of single-element associative arrays into grouped subarrays?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, grouping

I have an associative array:

```
Array ( 
[0] => Array ( [term_title] => black ) 
[1] => Array ( [color_quantity] => 2 ) 
[2] => Array ( [color_price] => 22 ) 
[3] => Array ( [term_title] => blue ) 
[4] => Array ( [color_quantity] => 3 ) 
[5] => Array ( [color_price] => 33 ))
```

How can I change it into:

```
Array ( 
[0] => Array ( [term_title] => black, [color_quantity] => 2, [color_price] => 22 ) 
[1] => Array ( [term_title] => blue, [color_quantity] => 3, [color_price] => 33 ) )
```

I try the following code:

```
$post = array();
for($i = 0; $i < 2; $i++){
    foreach($feild_data as $data){
        $post[$i][$data['name']] = $data['value'];
    }
}
```

but it repeat the last index two times. i.e.

```
Array ( 
[0] => Array ( [term_title] => blue, [color_quantity] => 3, [color_price] => 33 ) 
[1] => Array ( [term_title] => blue, [color_quantity] => 3, [color_price] => 33 ) )
```

Comment: What's the algorithm behind this change?

Comment: Your code refers to a few things which aren't in the output - `$post['item_' . $i]`, `$data['name']` and `$data['value']`, so not sure how you achieved the output you did.

Comment: I edit $post['item_' . $i] to $post[$i], its general.
$data is again an array with contain key and value as name and value. this array is come from an jQuery serializedArray from a form

Comment: @mickmackusa, not sure if the dupe really fits, in that case they are not using an associative array and so that will loose all of the keys (I think).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you like language constructs and basic arithmetic, then you can simply loop through the array, divide by 3 and use that float value as the first level key -- php will automatically `floor()` that value to form an integer

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/WL44T))

```
foreach ($array as $index => $subarray) {
    $key = key($subarray);
    $result[intdiv($index, 3)][$key] = $subarray[$key];
}
var_export($result);
```

Alternatively, if you prefer functional syntax (and I often do), you can form groups of subarrays, then merge/flatten the groups.  The technique below does not require the declaration of a `$result` variable and could be written as a one-liner.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/MSZbb))

```
var_export(
    array_map(
        function($v) {
            return array_merge(...$v);
        },
        array_chunk($array, 3)
    )
);
```

Both techniques provide the following output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'term_title' => 'black',
    'color_quantity' => 2,
    'color_price' => 22,
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'term_title' => 'blue',
    'color_quantity' => 3,
    'color_price' => 33,
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure from where `name` and `value` came in `$data['name']` and `$data['value']`, but you can use [`array_chunk`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php) to divide them in chunks and assign them to `$posts`.

```
<?php

$posts = array();
foreach(array_chunk($field_data,3) as $data){
    $temp = [];
    foreach($data as $field){
        foreach($field as $key => $value){
            $temp[$key] = $value;
        }
    }

    $posts[] = $temp;
}


print_r($posts);
```